# Common framework for Django, iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, django

we have a setup with a Django backend serving our native iOS and Android clients.

We have a couple of functions that we have implemented on each platform (for offline support etc) that we would like to have in a common framework.

My question is, is there any nice way to build a shared codebase that can run on these three platforms?

Comment: I honestly don't think it's worth to try to deploy the same code on 3 very different platforms. It make things very complicated instead of saving you time porting the code base.

Comment: The answer is of course simply "no". Also, why are you using Django? (It's 2015!) Just use any normal "bAAs" like Parse, Layer etc, the job will be done in a few hours.

Comment: @JoeBlow Our backend environment is quite extensive often running 20+ nodes. How would Parse solve my issue for instance?

Answer (score 0):

The three environments use very different languages. You have Java on Android, Swift or ObjectiveC on iOS and Python on your backend.

You may be able to embed Python in your mobile apps, and have them run a Python script (that will be the same code as the one you have on your backend), but it's going to take a while to get this just right.

I would keep the code implemented three times, unless it's *really* *really* complicated.